# selenium find all elements with a specific attribute

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to extract the texts in red rectagular in each 
    `<div class='c', id='M_D....'>` in the following pic.

I tried to use the following code:
    `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='ctt']").text()`
However, it just extract the text in the first `<div class='c', id='M_D....'>`. 
As shown in the picture, the page has many `<div class='c', id='M_D....'>`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMAw0.jpg

I tried:
    `all = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='ctt'][2]")`

Get an Error:
    `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)`
    `Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='ctt'][2]"}`

I'm new to selenium. I'm doing a commonweal project for human trafficking. Anyone could help me for this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all of the elements, you'll need to use the method that will retrieve a list of elements:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ctt']").text()
```

(Note that this will also retrieve the text of the link that's in this span)

Comment: text_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ctt']")  is right. It returns a list, which contains all the texts.  I can get the text according to  text_list[0].text(). Thanks to Breaks Software.